# Pandas ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects from single dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Ok, I thought this would be a simple way to find the rows where the value of a column was below the last value:

```
df.loc[df['Thing'] <= df['Thing'].tail(1)]
```

But I get

> 'ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects'

Researching that error message brings up causes where two dataframes are being compared, but in this case I'm using only one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df['Thing'].tail(1)` returns a Series with the last value, not the last value itself. Therefore you are trying to compare (`<=`) two different labelled Series, `df['Thing']` and `df['Thing'].tail(1)`, but `pandas` doesn't like it because it can't align their indices to perform the comparison.

Using [`.iat[-1]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) (or [`.iloc[-1]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html)) instead of `.tail(1)` should work:

```
df.loc[df['Thing'] <= df['Thing'].iat[-1]]
```